# Is it possible in any Java IDE to collapse the type definitions in the source code?

Tags: java, ide, folding

Lately I often have to read Java code like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> totals =  new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(listOfRows.get(0))
for (LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> row : (ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>>) table.getValue()) {    
    for(Entry<String, Integer> elem : row.entrySet()) {
        String colName=elem.getKey();
        int Value=elem.getValue();
        int oldValue=totals.get(colName);

        int sum = Value + oldValue;
        totals.put(colName, sum);
    }
}
```

Due to the long and nested type definitions the simple algorithm becomes quite obscured. So I wished I could remove or collapse the type definitions with my IDE to see the Java code without types like:

```
totals =  new (listOfRows.get(0))
for (row : table.getValue()) {    
    for(elem : row.entrySet()) {
        colName=elem.getKey();
        Value=elem.getValue();
        oldValue=totals.get(colName);

        sum = Value + oldValue;
        totals.put(colName, sum);
    }
}
```

The best way of course would be to collapse the type definitions, but when moving the mouse over a variable show the type as a tooltip. Is there a Java IDE or a plugin for an IDE that can do this?

Comment: .NET (Visual Studio) has this feature, they call it "region". I had tried to look for this feature in Eclipse a few months back, but I found nothing. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IntelliJ IDEA** will convert the types on the right-hand side of a declaration to `<~>`. So that:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Will appear folded as:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<~>();
```

This is settable via the *Editor / Code Folding / Generic Constructor and Method Parameters* property and the [community edition of the IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html) is free.

---

Or you could use **Scala**, which has type inference:

```
val totals = new mutable.Map[String, Int]
for { 
    row <- table.getValue
    (colName, value) <- row.entrySet 
} totals += (colName -> (value + totals.get(colName) getOrElse 0)
```